# Retrieve Blob data (pdf) using java in Google app Engine

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine

I have a database in which there is one field with Blob data. I want to put the download link on this file. i have used

```
resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
resp.getOutputStream().write(content.getBytes());
```

to get the pdf file.
I am able to get the file but it gets downloaded on the page in which this code is written.
I want to put the link with file name and on clicking the link i want to download this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [set the `Content-Disposition` header](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt).

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add a `target="_blank"` attribute in your download link:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://pathtothedownloadservlet">Download this pdf</a>
```

or, as said by Nick, use the Content Disposition like this:

```
resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
```

Comment: hi friends..i am able to download the file but that file name is shown as servlet name and it does not show the extension of the file??